# big brackets on an align environment

Tags: math-mode, align, matrices, brackets

I want my matrix to look like the one attached. I want my sum signs to be big and be in a matrix environment. Right now I am using the align environment and I am not quite sure how I can put brackets on it. Many thanks for the help!

```
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{8}x_i^2 \qquad \sum_{i=1}^{8}x_i \sin(x_i)\\
\sum_{i=1}^{8}x_i \sin(x_i) \qquad \sum_{i=1}^{8} \sin^2(x_i) \\
\end{align*}
```

Many thanks for the help[image]

Comment: Why don't you simply use the `pmatrix` environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `pmatrix` environments inside a simple display math environment. Then you can make the sum symbols bigger by placing `\displaystyle` in front of them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
    \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^8 x_i^2 & \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^8 x_i \sin(x_i) \\
    \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^8 x_i \sin(x_i) & \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^8 \sin^2(x_i)
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
    a \\ b
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^8 y_ix_i \\
    \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^8 y_i \sin(x_i)
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was pretty sure there had to be a simple solution to this issue :)

Answer (score 5):

Here are two variations on [@Vincent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/201628/vincent)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/596244/5001) which (a) use `pmatrix*` environments to left-align the cell contents and (b) use `\addlinespace` directives (provided by the `booktabs` package) to increase the separation between the rows of the matrix and the vector.

The first variation uses `\displaystyle` for each cell, and the second uses the default math style, *viz.*, `\textstyle`. Speaking for myself, I don't see a good use case for `\displaystyle` for the equation at hand.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'pmatrix*' env.
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for '\addlinespace' macro
\newcommand\mystrut{\vphantom{\sum_{i=1}^8}} % vertical spacers

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix*}[l]
    \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^8 x_i^2 & 
    \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^8 x_i \sin(x_i) \\ \addlinespace
    \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^8 x_i \sin(x_i) & 
    \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^8 \sin^2(x_i)
\end{pmatrix*} 
\begin{pmatrix}
    a \\[1ex] b
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix*}[l]
    \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^8 y_ix_i \\  \addlinespace
    \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^8 y_i \sin(x_i)
\end{pmatrix*}
\]


\[
\begin{pmatrix*}[l]
    \sum_{i=1}^8 x_i^2 & 
    \sum_{i=1}^8 x_i \sin(x_i) \\ \addlinespace
    \sum_{i=1}^8 x_i \sin(x_i) & 
    \sum_{i=1}^8 \sin^2(x_i)
\end{pmatrix*} 
\begin{pmatrix}
    a\mystrut \\ \addlinespace b\mystrut
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix*}[l]
    \sum_{i=1}^8 y_ix_i \\  \addlinespace
    \sum_{i=1}^8 y_i \sin(x_i)
\end{pmatrix*}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much as well! Do you know by any chance what's the simplest methode to increase or decrease the space between the COLUMNS in the upper example with the displaystyle? Have a great day and thanks again!

Comment: @GiovanniGorza - The amount of intercolumn whitespace in the `amsmath`/`mathtools` matrix-like environments is given `2\arraycolsep`. The default value of `\arraycolsep` for most (all?!) document classes is `5pt`. One may change `\arraycolsep` via `\setlength` and `\addtolength` statements. E.g., `\addtolength\arraycolsep{10pt}` or `\setlength\arraycolsep{7pt}`.